# Deploy a package on Windows by Jenkins running on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, jenkins

I have a Jenkins installed on a Linux build server and I need a project to be deployed on a Windows machine. Jenkins builds a simple zip package that contains an executable. The package can be uploaded with FTP.

But how to deploy that package after uploading? Call a batch script for example. For Linux servers I just use "Publish Over SSH Plugin" plugin.

Using Jenkins ver. 1.638.

Answer (score -2):

You need to know some powershell and use the Jenkins powershell plugin. 
But i propose your to Dockerize the project and deploy like that.